# Selecting by coordinates in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, coordinates, select-by-attribute

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.5.0 I've established a grid of points from a raster using the 'Raster to Point' tool and added the X and Y coordinates with 'Add Geometry Attributes'.
I now need to select a subset of points on a certain latitude. Using the 'Select Layer By Attribute' tool I specify the exact POINT_Y but the selection does not return results, in contrast to searching by OBJECTID. I assume this is due to rounding errors - the decimals displayed are not the decimals given when I click the actual value (in the case of the value in the image, I get -5.98330575 when I double click on the field).

[image]

I've tried both values and also tried to change the number of decimals displayed, but still selecting by POINT_Y fails. Is there another tool to achieve this or a way to set decimals when calculating the point coordinates in the first place?